# Using Python scripts create dynamic html file

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Using the below Python scripts i can able to create html file  by already set the variables(a,b,c,d) as global.I want to run the script dynamically, even also i don't set some variables as globally ,for eg: if we didn't set the value of "a" as global it throwing error "global 'a' is not defined".So please let me know any python scripts for dynamically taking the values and convert them in to html table.

```
import HTML
import html2 
from html2 import *
#print a
#print b
file = open('out.html', 'w') 
table_data = [
['S.No',   'Testcase - ID',   'Result'],
['1',       a,         b],
['2',       c,         d],

]
htmlcode = HTML.table(table_data)
c=htmlcode
print htmlcode
file.write(c)
```

Comment: Taking the values from where?

Comment: It is in seperate file html2, so we give import html2.

Answer (score 3):

`table_data` needs `a`, `b`, etc. to be defined. It incorporates their values into a *new* global.

This has otherwise *nothing* to do with `HTML.table()`; your `table_data` list cannot be defined as it currently stands without `a` and `b` being defined as well.

If you want `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` used as parameters from another module, you need to make this a function:

```
def create_table(a, b, c, d):
    table_data = [
    ['S.No',   'Testcase - ID',   'Result'],
    ['1',       a,         b],
    ['2',       c,         d],

    ]
    return HTML.table(table_data)
```

Now you can call `create_table()` with different parameters.

Comment: Thanks Martijin for your reply, but we using this script to get the final output as HTML file, so we take regular expression and store the variables as output and again declare that variable as global then call the variable in html Scripts here we set, a-TC-01 ,b-Passed,c-TC-02,d- Passed:  but if we didnt run Testcase 1 we cannot able to take the output and store the variable in 'a' and 'b'on that case it throwing error "global a is not defined" so please let me know any python scripts to take the values dynamically.